# How to profile a unit test in Netbeans?

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans, profiling

How do you profile a unit test in Netbeans 6.9 running on Ubuntu?

My research indicates that you use the "Profile test for ..." menu item. From the main menu you can see it at: Profile : Profile Other : Profile test for ClassName.

In my case the menu is always disabled. What do you do to enable this?

Answer (score 7):

The Profile Test For File menu will only be enabled when a testable class is selected, either in the project window or opened. It will not be enabled when the test class is selected!

Comment: Old thread so things will have changed -- but I'm not seeing this in NetBeans 9.  The `Profile File` and `Profile Test File` items in both the main `Profile` menu and the context menu for source and test remain greyed out.  Only have the option to `Profile Project` (EJB) which isn't desirable at this stage.

Comment: Okay so *NetBeans* does not support profiling files or tests within an *EJB* project, only the whole shebang.